# How do I close flow in mitmproxy web interface (mitmweb)

Tags: mitmproxy

Clicking a row in mitmweb opens details of a flow. But how do I close it and go back to my previous list view ?

Before
[image]

After clicking a row
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can, for example, press `Esc` to deselect the flow.

Comment: Yes this works. Are other keybindings documented somewhere?